# Handle blurring of each field in a form with jQUery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onblur

I've got a form and I need to post data to the server every time a field in the form is changed. How do I apply a function to each child element of the form on blur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('form#yourform > input').blur(function(){
    // Do Server Request here.
});
```

Comment: Make sure to hit <select> and <textarea> elements too.

Answer (score 0):

I've created `update()` as the function that posts to the server and used the following:

```
        $( 'input' ).blur( function() {
            update();
        }); 

        $( 'input[type=checkbox]' ).click( function() {
            update();
        });

        $( 'textarea' ).blur( function() {
            update();
        });

        $( 'select' ).change( function() {
            update();
        });
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.4.2 you can just do `$('form').change(update)`.

Comment: Isn't the $ selector conducive to CSS style selectors? Why not have one single selector to rule them all, and save yourself the function call?

$('input, input[type=checkbox], textarea, select').blur(function() { });

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

$('input, select').blur(function(){
    // function definition
});

Also:

$('form input, form select').blur(function(){
    // function definition
});